Trying to for_each over a map of maps
I have the following code that I would like to iterate over its map.
resource "aws_autoscaling_group_tag" "test" {
  for_each = {
      host1 = {
        "foo1" = "bar1"
        "foo2" = "bar2"
      }
      host2 = {
        "foo1" = "bar1"
        "foo2" = "bar2"
      }
  }

  autoscaling_group_name = "doesnt-matter-getting-from-elsewhere"

  tag {
    key                 = each.key
    value               = each.value
    propagate_at_launch = false  
  } 
}

This produces the following error stating that value is not a string, which I get because it's getting a map.

│ Error: Incorrect attribute value type
│
│   on main.tf line 62, in resource "aws_autoscaling_group_tag" "test":
│   62:     value = each.value
│     ├────────────────
│     │ each.value is object with 2 attributes
│
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "value": string required.
╵
╷
│ Error: Incorrect attribute value type
│
│   on main.tf line 62, in resource "aws_autoscaling_group_tag" "test":
│   62:     value = each.value
│     ├────────────────
│     │ each.value is object with 2 attributes
│
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "value": string required.

What I'm actually trying to reproduce is this terraform code:
resource "aws_autoscaling_group_tag" "test" {

  autoscaling_group_name = "doesnt-matter-getting-from-elsewhere1"

  tag {
    key                 = "foo1"
    value               = "bar1"
    propagate_at_launch = false  
  } 
}

resource "aws_autoscaling_group_tag" "test" {

  autoscaling_group_name = "doesnt-matter-getting-from-elsewhere1"

  tag {
    key                 = "foo2"
    value               = "bar2"
    propagate_at_launch = false  
  } 
}

resource "aws_autoscaling_group_tag" "test" {

  autoscaling_group_name = "doesnt-matter-getting-from-elsewhere2"

  tag {
    key                 = "foo1"
    value               = "bar1"
    propagate_at_launch = false  
  } 
}

resource "aws_autoscaling_group_tag" "test" {

  autoscaling_group_name = "doesnt-matter-getting-from-elsewhere2"

  tag {
    key                 = "foo2"
    value               = "bar2"
    propagate_at_launch = false  
  } 
}

this problem is probably trivial to good terraformers, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Why do you need host1 and host2?

You can use a nested for loop and the merge function to flatten the maps.
Working example using the null_resource:
locals {
  hosts = {
    host1 = {
      "foo1" = "bar1"
      "foo2" = "bar2"
    }
    host2 = {
      "foo1" = "bar1"
      "foo2" = "bar2"
    }
  }

  flattened_tags = merge([
    for host, tags in local.hosts : {
      for tag, value in tags : "${host}.${tag}" => {
        host      = host
        tag_name  = tag
        tag_value = value
      }
    }
  ]...)
}

resource "null_resource" "example" {
  for_each = local.flattened_tags

  triggers = {
    host      = each.value.host
    tag_name  = each.value.tag_name
    tag_value = each.value.tag_value
  }
}

output "tags" {
  value = local.flattened_tags
}

Running terraform plan:
Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution
plan. Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  + create

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # null_resource.example["host1.foo1"] will be created
  + resource "null_resource" "example" {
      + id       = (known after apply)
      + triggers = {
          + "host"      = "host1"
          + "tag_name"  = "foo1"
          + "tag_value" = "bar1"
        }
    }

  # null_resource.example["host1.foo2"] will be created
  + resource "null_resource" "example" {
      + id       = (known after apply)
      + triggers = {
          + "host"      = "host1"
          + "tag_name"  = "foo2"
          + "tag_value" = "bar2"
        }
    }

  # null_resource.example["host2.foo1"] will be created
  + resource "null_resource" "example" {
      + id       = (known after apply)
      + triggers = {
          + "host"      = "host2"
          + "tag_name"  = "foo1"
          + "tag_value" = "bar1"
        }
    }

  # null_resource.example["host2.foo2"] will be created
  + resource "null_resource" "example" {
      + id       = (known after apply)
      + triggers = {
          + "host"      = "host2"
          + "tag_name"  = "foo2"
          + "tag_value" = "bar2"
        }
    }

Plan: 4 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.

Changes to Outputs:
  + tags = {
      + "host1.foo1" = {
          + host      = "host1"
          + tag_name  = "foo1"
          + tag_value = "bar1"
        }
      + "host1.foo2" = {
          + host      = "host1"
          + tag_name  = "foo2"
          + tag_value = "bar2"
        }
      + "host2.foo1" = {
          + host      = "host2"
          + tag_name  = "foo1"
          + tag_value = "bar1"
        }
      + "host2.foo2" = {
          + host      = "host2"
          + tag_name  = "foo2"
          + tag_value = "bar2"
        }
    }

See Grouping results to understand how to use the ellipsis operator ...
